# Elan touchpad i2c_hid problem

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, elantech

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on my Asus convertible laptop, but it is now erratic upon resuming from standby. Quite often I will get a message saying something like "i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (16/16466)". This wasn't happening under 17.10. I'd be glad to send along any logfiles that could be helpful. Any ideas as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The system won't do anything else when this message appears. I can't change to a different virtual terminal to initiate a reboot or to restart xorg, I have to do a hard power down.